# JavaFX: How to add a checkbox and a button in a TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX.

I am trying to include a checkbox, a label and a button in each column in a tree table below the root.

Is it possible to do that? Help me with the solution and a few reference code for the same.

Thanks,
Vevek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is set the cell factory for the tree view.

A quick response to your comment:
Just to be clear on the terminology. A tree structure (which is implemented in `TreeView`) consists of nodes. A node can have many children and one parent. A node without any parents is a root node. A node without any children is a leaf. There can only be one root node per tree.

But what you can do in a `TreeView` is hide the root node. If you add several children to the root node, and then hide the root node, it will look like you have several root nodes. Any node in a `TreeView`, including the root, is a `TreeItem`, and you can always add a child to a `TreeItem` by adding a `TreeItem`to it, and this child can then have it's own children, etc. So you can add as many different levels of nodes as you like.

Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox view = new VBox();
        view.setPrefSize(600, 400);

        // Creating the root node
        final TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root node");
        root.setExpanded(true);

        // Creating the tree items that will be the first children of the root node
        // and the parent to the child nodes.
        final TreeItem<String> parentNode1 = new TreeItem<>("Parent node 1");
        final TreeItem<String> parentNode2 = new TreeItem<>("Parent node 2");
        final TreeItem<String> parentNode3 = new TreeItem<>("Parent node 3");

        // Creating the tree items that will be the children of the parent
        // nodes.
        final TreeItem<String> childNode1 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 1");
        final TreeItem<String> childNode2 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 2");
        final TreeItem<String> childNode3 = new TreeItem<>("Child Node 3");

        // Adding tree items to the root
        root.getChildren().setAll(parentNode1, parentNode2, parentNode3);

        // Add the child nodes to all children of the root
        for (TreeItem<String> parent : root.getChildren()) {
            parent.getChildren().addAll(childNode1, childNode2, childNode3);
        }

        // Creating a tree table view
        final TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);

        // We set show root to false. This will hide the root and only show it's children in the treeview.
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        treeView.setCellFactory(e -> new CustomCell());

        view.getChildren().add(treeView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(view);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * A custom cell that shows a checkbox, label and button in the
     * TreeCell.
     */
    class CustomCell extends TreeCell<String> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            // If the cell is empty we don't show anything.
            if (isEmpty()) {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            } else {
                // We only show the custom cell if it is a leaf, meaning it has
                // no children.
                if (this.getTreeItem().isLeaf()) {

                    // A custom HBox that will contain your check box, label and
                    // button.
                    HBox cellBox = new HBox(10);

                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                    Label label = new Label(item);
                    Button button = new Button("Press!");
                    // Here we bind the pref height of the label to the height of the checkbox. This way the label and the checkbox will have the same size. 
                    label.prefHeightProperty().bind(checkBox.heightProperty());

                    cellBox.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, label, button);

                    // We set the cellBox as the graphic of the cell.
                    setGraphic(cellBox);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    // If this is the root we just display the text.
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Also see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) for the `Cell` class on how to provide a custom cell factory.

Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there any possibility to develop a visible borders to the tree table with the column name as well

Comment: Oh you wanted a `TreeTableView` and not a `TreeView`. I've updated my answer with a second example. There are already borders surrounding the whole tree table view as well as each column header. Do you want to add your own borders anyway?

Comment: Did you get your answer? If so: Please mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise feel free to ask further questions!

Comment: Treeview is okay for me. But how can i add second, third and further root nodes and their corresponding child nodes. I need a tree structure like rootnode1 with its child nodes(checkbox, label and button), rootnode2 with child nodes(Checkbox, label and button). Please help me out.

Comment: What you want to do then is hide the root. Check my revised answer and please read the text regarding the terminology.